# Alamofire get response String with line break in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, httpresponse, swift5

I am working on swift project and I need to get response string from server.
But the main problem is that response string is consist of several lines and I tried to fetch this data using Alarmofire, but I got failed.
This is code:

```
AF.request(baseURL).responseString { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

And I got following response

```
[Request]: GET https://rs.allisonhouse.com/feeds/***/lsr.php
[Request Body]: 
None
[Response]: 
[Status Code]: 200
[Headers]:
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
CF-RAY: 5a78e097da8305aa-LAX
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 20:56:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 02:37:15 GMT
Server: cloudflare
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Via: 1.1 google
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cf-request-id: 037f6ab2ea000005aa92a15200000001
[Response Body]: 
You must use a supported software<br>
If you are have having issues contact support@allisonhouse.com

[Data]: 101 bytes
[Network Duration]: 0.9248800277709961s
[Serialization Duration]: 7.49826431274414e-05s
[Result]: success("You must use a supported software<br>\nIf you are have having issues contact support@allisonhouse.com\n")
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Figure out what they consider "supported software". Perhaps they don't support people making arbitrary requests.

Comment: why you don't try to use `.responseJSON` ?

Comment: Because response is not json string, it's common string.

Answer (score 0):

This is my server that you’re hitting.

We check the User-Agent header to prevent unauthorized access. Contact me by email to discuss your use case and receive authorization.